# In clustering, sequence number such as customer ID and dates such as purchase date should be dropped?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am learning K-means clustering and found that in most datasets, there are sequence number such as customer ID and dates such as purchase date.
I don't see any use in them for clustering.
Should I include them for clustering or can simply ignore them?
Let's say other attributes are like purchase amount and number of purchases and etc.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely drop dates and unique identifiers for clustering.

Comment: @JayaramIyer thank you, yes, the result of clustering including customer number is totally different than the results without the customer number. It seems adding the customer ruins the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should drop the customer ID since it's a unique identifier and won't give you any additional value.
Instead, I would be rather cautious with the date. The date can be split into year, month and day. Depending on the analysis you are doing, it might be interesting to have K-means running also with those features.
For instance, suppose that you want to check whether you have some blobs of data in a specific period of the year, you should use the month feature.

Comment: right, thank you. customer ID makes the outcome totally different but except it, including other attributes makes the similar patterns of the outcomes. I will try to use the date as you suggested, I will split it into years or month. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we use K-mean clustering to label the unlabelled dataset where customer id is a unique identifier that doesn't add value to perform clustering but after clustering we assign cluster outcome or the labels to the customer id to specify which customer belongs to which category. Therefore, based on your purpose, you can drop out the customer id from the dataset or can keep it separately to label them after clustering.

The date and times are important if you want to perform RFM (Recency, Frequency and Monetary) analysis. Otherwise this feature may also be ignored.